# Magento Soap API V2 salesOrderInfo not returning custom field

Tags: php, magento, soap, wsdl

I'm using the Magento SOAP V2 API (php) to retrieve order information (salesOrderInfo). This returns an object with a shipping_address and billing_address property. For example:

```
[shipping_address] => stdClass Object
    (
        [parent_id] => 564
        [address_type] => shipping
        [firstname] => John
        [lastname] => Doe
        [company] => Johns shop
        [street] => Mystreet
        [city] => Mycity
        [postcode] => 12345
        [country_id] => NL
        [telephone] => 012345678
        [address_id] => 1128
    )
```

We use a custom property ("house") to store the house-number, but this property is not returned. I already tried adding it in /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/wsdl.xml, but still no luck.

When I remove for example the "postcode" field in the wsdl.xml file, it does affect the returned object (the postcode-property is not returned).

What am I missing? How can I add this field to the SOAP response?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by clearing the wsdl cache:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient('http://server.com/?wsdl', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE) );
```